# An object having a general plane motion exerting force on air

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

assume that we have ball that's both spinning and moving in a straight path through the air.
Does the ball exert a force **at right angles to the path it's moving** on the air?
[image]
If the answer is yes, please explain how is that possible!

Comment: Yeah, check out the Magnus Effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a spinning ball will produce a force perpendicular to the direction of it's path of travel through air.

This is called the [Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect).  The fluid dynamics that lead to this are fairly complicated, and I don't know them well enough to do it justice.  The simplified version of events is that due to those complicated fluid dynamics effects, the spinning ball causes the air stream to deflect based on the direction that the ball is spinning.  That deflection requires a force from the ball, and the equal and opposite reaction to that force produces a force perpendicular to the direction of travel for the ball.

Something similar happens with airplanes.  The wings deflect the air downwards, and the plane pushes up against that.